# While is not working properly

Tags: java

```
System.out.println("A or B");
   option = input.nextLine().toLowerCase();
   while(!"a".equals(option) || !"b".equals(option)) {
       System.out.print("Incorrect character");
       option = input.nextLine().toLowerCase();
   }
```

Im trying to make the program say "Incorrect character" if the variable option is not 'a' or 'b' and then ask for input again.
But the program keeps saying "Incorrect character" even if i type 'a' or 'b'.

Comment: Well if you enter "a", what would be the boolean value of `!"a".equals(option) || !"b".equals(option)` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be

```
while(!"a".equals(option) && !"b".equals(option))
```

Using an OR condition, as you currently do, means that the condition is always true, and the loop never exits.